# Will modifying app capabilities invalidate any provisioning profiles that include this App ID?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

I have an enterprise app already in use. And I need to add some capabilities for it. If I save the edit of the capabilities list, a popup appears:

Modify App Capabilities Adding or removing any capabilities will invalidate any provisioning profiles that include this App ID and they must be regenerated for future use.

So, I want to know that if I click "save", the app using the previous profile can still be installed or not? And will it impact the app already installed?

Comment: Any inputs on this?

Answer (score 2):

No. This only affects new apps you sign. Existing apps will continue to work until the embedded profile expires.

Comment: It seems that this answer comes from this thread: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656835. I'd flag the answer for plaigarism but it seems like it's helped at least one person so thought I'd just provide the context instead.